# Allow Facebook user to block another Facebook user in my app

Tags: facebook

I want to allow a user of my web app to block someone on Facebook. Is this possible using the Facebook API/SDK? Assuming that I have the user's access token and proper permissions.

I can see that I'm able to ban a user from using my app by POSTing to the `/v2.6/{app-id}/banned` edge, but I want the user to be able to block another user from seeing their Facebook profile in general.

```
POST /v2.6/{app-id}/banned HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com

uid=1234
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/app/banned

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: @WizKid I know it's difficult to back up a claim of something _not_ being possible, but do you by chance have any sources for this?

Comment: It is not listed at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user which it would if it existed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by [WizKid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230840/allow-facebook-user-to-block-another-facebook-user-in-my-app#comment63883911_38230840) in the comments (he is an an employee for Facebook) if the edge doesn't appear in the reference listed at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user then it's not possible.